# Abstract Method Override With Derived Class Argument

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    
    public abstract bool IsMatch(Person person);
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public override bool IsMatch(Employee person)
    {
        return Id == person.Id;
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like my override of the IsMatch method.

1. Why is this? Empolyee is a Person so why is it complaining?
2. What is the best way around this? Would I need to cast to Employee in the IsMatch override?

Thanks.

Comment: `Person` and `Employee` are different types, `IsMatch` should have the same signature

Comment: Perhaps you should dig into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type and or the hash code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this? Empolyee is a Person so why is it complaining?

Because you have to override with the same signature, not one that's similar. In some cases it would seem reasonable, but in this case it's definitely *not* reasonable. Consider the following:

```cs
public class Customer : Person
{
}
...

Person employee = new Employee();
Person customer = new Customer();
bool match = employee.IsMatch(customer);
```

That should definitely compile with no problems - I'm calling `IsMatch` on the abstract `Person` class; the compiler doesn't "know" that `employee` actually refers to an `Employee`. So how would you expect that to execute? It couldn't enter your implementation of `IsMatch`, because we're passing a customer.

> What is the best way around this?

That's hard to say without knowing more about the situation. You *could* implement `Employee.IsMatch` like this instead:

```cs
public override bool IsMatch(Person person) =>
    person is Employee employee && Id == employee.Id;
```

That *may* be the right thing to do, but we don't really know.